# Trimming every line in a text file then saving the result to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, trim

I need to read a local text file which will have a file name on every line. Every file name needs to be trimmed of it's extension. When I get to the part where I need to save the result of the trimming to another array I'm having some trouble.

So far I have:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\path\file.txt";

      string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
      foreach (string s in readText)
      {
          string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s);

          //here I can print the result to the screen 
          //but I don't know how to save to another array for further manipulation    

      }
```

If you need any further clarification I will do my best to be more clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just pushback the value into a vector?

Comment: @Papsicle Sorry I don't know what that means. In order to grow on this site I have to make a few posts so I can have enough rep to vote and show my appreciation on the hundreds of posts I read on here every work day. Still a noob.

Comment: A vector is a dynamic array, meaning you don't have to specify it's length when creating it, it will automatically increase in size when full. So you can create a local vector and then just use the pushback method (which is really just an add method) and add every string value you have into this dynamic array. You could read out more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Papsicle. Now that you explain it I vaguely remember that subject, I'm gonna take a look now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\path\file.txt";
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
for( int i = 0; i < readText.Length; i++ )
    readText[i] = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( readText[i] );
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. And no I didn't need to save the original array.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with Linq:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\path\file.txt";
var trimmed =
    File.ReadAllLines(path)
        .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate a new array of the same size as the original array, and then insert by indexing.

```
  string path = @"C:\Users\path\file.txt";

  string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
  string[] outputArray = new string[readText.Length];
  int index = 0;
  foreach (string s in readText)
  {
      outputArray[index++] = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s);
  }
```